# Using code contracts in one property to provide hints about another property

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, resharper, code-contracts

I have a `struct` like this (simplified for brevity):

```
public struct Period
{
    public DateTime? Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; private set; }

    public bool IsMoment
    {
        get { return this.Start.HasValue && this.Start == this.End; }
    }

    public Period(DateTime? start, DateTime? end) : this()
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.IsMoment 
            ? this.Start.Value.ToString("g") 
            : string.Format("{0:g} – {1:g}", this.Start, this.End);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but ReSharper is showing a warning on `this.Start.Value.ToString`:

> Possible '`System.InvalidOperationException`'

If I copy the body of the `IsMoment` property into the condition, the warning goes away, but I'd like to be able to reuse the property. I can disable the ReSharper warning with a comment (which is what I have done for the moment), or by changing `ToString` to `string.Format`, but I have a handful of other places like this in my code and it got me thinking. I'd try to resolve this using [code contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but unfortunately I don't have a whole lot of experience with code contracts and I'm not sure how it would look.

Is there anyway I use code contracts to indicate to ReSharper that if `IsMoment` is `true`, then `Start` is not `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this in IsMoment:

contract.ensures(result == false || start <> null);

(That's not exactly right. I'm typing this on my phone.)

UPDATE:

The problem could be due to the possibility of multithreaded code changing the value of Start between the IsMoment test and the Start.Value evaluation.

It may be more correct to copy the value into a local variable that cannot be modified by other threads.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    Period local = this;
    return local.IsMoment 
        ? local.Start.Value.ToString("g") 
        : string.Format("{0:g} – {1:g}", local.Start, local.End);
}
```

This looks like some unnecessary work, and it may look inefficient, but it more "correct". If your struct is small, though, this may actually be more efficient in many cases.

Comment: This idea looks promising. I tried `Contract.Ensures(!Contract.Result<bool>() || this.Start.HasValue)` and several other variations. Unfortunately none of them seem to work. The ReSharper warning is still there.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer. It appears to make the static contracts checker happy, but not ReSharper. I'm guessing ReSharper's checker is not sophisticated enough to inspect the contracts defined in other properties or methods (or at least not in this case). In the end, I changed it to `this.Start.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("g")`, which satisfies ReSharper, and I think it may even be marginally more efficient bypasses the `Nullable`'s `HasValue` check.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried wrapping parens around it?

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return (this.IsMoment 
        ? this.Start.Value.ToString("g") 
        : string.Format("{0:g} – {1:g}", this.Start, this.End));
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't change the behavior. I've also tried a few other forms, including changing the `?:` to an `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case for using `Contract.Assume`.

```
public override string ToString()
{
   if (this.IsMoment) {
      Contract.Assume(this.Start.HasValue);
      return this.Start.Value.ToString("g");
   }
   else
      return string.Format("{0:g} – {1:g}", this.Start, this.End));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed resolve the error, but I would have to copy this to every place where I'm calling `IsMoment`. I was hoping to do this with contracts inside `IsMoment`.